# ngRoute not working in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Here's the main index:
I have two .php files which needs to be viewed in template.(ng-view)
mainFrame.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-US" ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link href="../css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/blogmain.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700italic,900|Lato|Tangerine|Montserrat|Robot
        o+Condensed:400,300italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar-fixed">
            <nav style="height: 65px">
                <div class="nav-wrapper">
                    <a href="#" class="brand-logo center" style="font-family:'Montserrat',serif;">
                        Welcome To </a>
                    <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
                        <li class="waves-effect wifull"><a href="#/create" id="changeDiv">Create a
                                Post</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="waves-effect wifull"><a href="#/posts" id="changeDiv1">View
                                Posts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse show-on-large show-on-medium-and-down"><i
                            class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular_min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular_route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/appRoute.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('select').material_select();
        });
        $('.button-collapse').sideNav({
                menuWidth: 300,
                edge: 'left',
                closeOnClick: true
            }
        );
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

.js file for routing.

appRoute.js

```
   (function () {
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider
        .when('/create', {
            templateUrl: '../create/create.php',
            controller: 'CreateController'
        })
        .when('/posts', {
                templateUrl: '../viewPost/view_post.php',
                controller: 'ViewPostController'
            }
        )
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/create'
        })
});

app.controller('CreateController', function ($scope) {
});

app.controller('ViewPostController', function ($scope) {
});

}).();
```

I don't know what's the problem but nothing is being shown in ng-view.
Thanks.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: No errors, though I get nothing inside  <div ng-view></div>. It's empty.

Comment: Why do you have ../ in front of your path? Does your 'otherwise' works?

Comment: I am getting no result even if I go to link ' mainFrame.php#/posts '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second variant of code :) Only put normal HTML templates

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', 
 function($location, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/create', {
            templateUrl: '../create/create.php',
            controller: 'CreateController'
        })
        .when('/posts', {
                templateUrl: '../viewPost/view_post.php',
                controller: 'ViewPostController'
            }
        )
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/create'
        })
}]);

app.controller('CreateController', function ($scope) {
});

app.controller('ViewPostController', function ($scope) {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last line in appRoute.js is wrong.

```
}).();
```

Just remove the . (dot)

```
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

For first, it's bad idea to use JQuery and Angular inside one JS App.

Second, what .();   in the end of code in appRoute.js ?

Third, do you have code with call   in  appRoute.js  (function () {  ?

So try this code for appRoute.js

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider
        .when('/create', {
            templateUrl: '../create/create.php',
            controller: 'CreateController'
        })
        .when('/posts', {
                templateUrl: '../viewPost/view_post.php',
                controller: 'ViewPostController'
            }
        )
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/create'
        })
});

app.controller('CreateController', function ($scope) {
});

app.controller('ViewPostController', function ($scope) {
});
```

Comment: Now my otherwise code is working but still nothing inside ng-view.

Comment: Sure, you have nothing. You try to use ../create/create.php and ../viewPost/view_post.php 
But you need Client-Side template, not a Server-Side!
This is part of my App

app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', 
  function($location, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/signin.html',
            controller: 'UserCtrl'
        }).

Comment: I tried it with a normal html file(templateUrl) with some <p></p> but its showing nothing.

Comment: Try to check path for html templates, try open template in browser with url you wrote in $routeProvider

Comment: The problem was that appRoute.js wasn't in the same level directory as mainFrame. Now it's working.(.php is working fine.)